In QT6.5, when using QGraphicsView to center an image, the white space outside the image cannot be displayed, resulting in a centering failure
As shown in Figure 1, I want to implement clicking on the green rectangle to jump the green rectangle to the center, and if the green rectangle is closer to the border, it should be centered and appear blank where the Image is not shown。

as shown in Figure 2. Now the problem is that I can't implement the function of displaying white space where Image is not displayed。

the mouse click event has been overloaded, as follows:
class CustomGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomGraphicsView(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsView(parent) {
        setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white);
    }
signals:
    void mouseClicked(const QPointF& pos);
protected:
   
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override {
        QPoint viewportPos = event->pos();
        QPointF scenePos = mapToScene(viewportPos);
        emit mouseClicked(scenePos);
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
};

When the mousecliked signal was activated, it executed the following function：
void MainWindow::onMouseClicked(const QPointF& pos)
{
    qDebug() << "Mouse clicked at scene position:" << pos;

    QString textContent = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QTextStream stream(&textContent);
    //The program may have multiple rectangles
    //xe, ye are the top-left coordinates, and rect represents the length and width of the rectangle
    for(int i = 0;i<xe.size();i++)
    {
        if(pos.x()>=xe[i] && pos.x()<=xe[i]+rectWidthe[i])
            if(pos.y()>=ye[i] && pos.y()<=ye[i]+rectHighte[i])
            {
                QPointF pos1;
                //pos1 is the center point of the rectangle
                pos1.setX(xe[i]+rectWidthe[i]/2);
                pos1.setY(ye[i]+rectHighte[i]/2);
                ui->Image->centerOn(pos1);
                return;
            }
    }
}


The only relatively simple option to achieve this is by changing the sceneRect, with the obvious result that this will also change the scroll bar values.

Can you expand on how to use it, or can you demonstrate a sample code? Thank you!

I cannot provide any example as I don't write in C++, but the implementation is quite elementary as long as you have basic knowledget of the graphics view framework and elementary math/geometry knowledge: 1. get the view's viewport(); 2. use mapToScene() to get its mapped polygon in scene coordinates; 3. get its boundingRect(); 4. use moveCenter() based on the item's sceneBoundingRect().center(); 5. call setSceneRect() with the same rect. Obviously, if the scene is larger than the view (showing scroll bars), things are a bit more complex, but they always will be in such cases.

The whole point is that, by default, the graphics view only shows the maximum possible extent of the scene within its sceneRect(). If the top of that rect is 0, you cannot display anything above it unless the view has a height bigger than that of the scene (considering transforms). While going beyond those boundaries is possible, it requires more knowledge about the Graphics View framework and QAbstractScrollArea (including QAbstractScrollBar) in general, because what you want to achieve goes beyond the current scroll limits: you cannot center something that exists above the top margin.
